Was using an older version of a legal card from a nonlegal set ever not legal?
In Magic the Gathering, some formats only allow you to play cards printed from certain sets.
However, some cards printed into sets are reprints of older cards - the current (black-bordered) magic rules consider these cards to be functionally identical to the cards in the newer sets, and thus playing a card from a non-legal set is allowed as long as it has been reprinted in a legal set.
I was wondering if this was always the case, rules-wise, and if not, when it was changed?

No, cards with the same name have always been legal to play, regardless of the set they were printed in.
For deckbuilding purposes, the English name of a card has always been the only deciding factor for card identity. This is the only practical option anyway, considering that base sets from Beta (1993) up to and including Tenth Edition (2007) consisted of nothing but reprints.
Today's rules for card identity and deck construction are as follows:

100.2a In constructed play (a way of playing in which each player creates their own deck ahead of time), each deck has a minimum deck size of 60 cards. A constructed deck may contain any number of basic land cards and no more than four of any card with a particular English name other than basic land cards.


201.2. A card’s name is always considered to be the English version of its name, regardless of printed language.

The current Magic Tournament Rules say this:

A card may only be used in a particular format if the card is from a set that is legal in that format or has the same name as a card from a set that is legal in that format.

Petr Hudeček's blog hosts a collection of old (pre-2016) rules. I don't know if that collection is complete, but for what it's worth, the earliest version of the Comprehensive Rules (CR) it has that resembles the modern format is from 1999. On deck construction and card identity, it has this to say:

100.2. In constructed-deck play, each player needs his or her own deck of at least sixty cards with no more than four copies of any card except basic lands; small objects to represent any tokens and counters; and some way to clearly track life totals.


202.3. Two cards are considered to have the same name if the English versions of their names are identical, regardless of anything else printed on the cards.

The first tournament rules are from a 1994 usenet entry and state:


There may be no more than 4 of any individual card in
the tournament deck (including sideboard), with the exception of
the 5 basic land types (Plains, Forest, Mountain, Island, Swamp). [..]




Decks may be constructed from cards from the Limited
(black border) series and from the Unlimited (white border)
series. [..]


Even though the modern rules state the "reprints allowed" rule explicitely, it still references card names as the only deciding factor.

Well, arguably Alpha wasn't a reprint set, given that there was nothing to reprint at the time :-)

No, cards with the same name have always been legal to play, regardless of the set they were printed in. This is strictly not true. The 30th-anniversary reprints sets (The one that cost a thousand dollars for a pack) are not legal anywhere even though they have cards with legal names. The gold border World Championship decks have cards that are not legal for tournament and also the Collector's set for beta.

There is also the 93/94 format which stipulates that you can only use cards from those years and not the much cheaper newer versions

The 30th anniversary set is not legal in any sanctioned format, so the cards in it are not reprints in the sense of the question. The 93/94 format is not an official format and thus not covered by official rules, so I wouldn't have discussed it even if I had known about it.

There was at least one tournament where basic lands from unglued were not legal to play. An out of cycle rules adjustment was required to fix it.

There's one tournament I know of in which it might not have been legal to freely use older versions of reprinted cards: the first Pro Tour in February 1996. The format for this tournament was a variant of Standard/Type II in which players were required to use at least five cards from every Standard-legal set. I don't know if this literally meant using five cards actually printed in each set, or if you would just have to submit a decklist which could be constructed using at least five cards from each set but the actual cards you used could be from other sets. And even if the five cards from each set did have to be printings from that exact set, there were only five sets in Standard/Type II at the time, so presumably any of the remaining 50 cards could be older printings. Still, this is the only situation I can think of in which it might not have been acceptable to substitute in an older printing of some card.
I checked a few sources to see if I could find any definitive statement of what the five-card-per-set rule meant: the article I linked, issues 8 and 10 of The Duelist, various wiki pages, and my copy of The Tables of Magic which includes a tournament report by one of the top 8 players, but I came up empty. I also found a YouTube video featuring coverage from the tournament but didn't have time to watch it to see if it said anything about this. However... this was from an era where a card's expansion was still meaningful, since effects like Apocalypse Chime and Golgothian Sylex, which affected all cards from a particular expansion, would look at the expansion the actual physical card came from. It wasn't until 2013 that they were errata'd to refer to "cards originally printed in ..." and Magic finally got to the point where different cards with the same name were 100% interchangeable in gameplay. Given that, I would think that if players in PT '96 were allowed to use older printings of their five cards per set, it would likely have been mentioned somewhere, and the fact that I didn't find that makes it seem plausible that the five cards from each set had to actually be printings from that set. Speculation, of course, but it may be hard to find anything more definitive.

I knew of that tournament, but the rule had nothing to do with reprints. It was about forcing players to use Homelands and other expansions: How can you ensure that Homelands cards show up in the winning Pro Tour deck when very few Homelands cards were showing up in tournaments? Just force every deck to play at least five of them.

Yeah I know why the rule was put in place, I read the article I linked to ;-) The operative question is, if a card was reprinted in Homelands, does an earlier printing of that card count as a card from Homelands for purposes of the five-from-each-set rule? (and likewise for each other set) That's what it has to do with reprints.

Homelands contains no reprints, so it could not prevent old cards being played on those grounds.

As I said in my comment, "and likewise for each other set"

I stand corrected, Ice Age was legal and it of course does have base set reprints, at least Counterspell and CIrcles of Protection. So yes, that was probably a one-off where using older cards might have been illegal, depending on how it was enforced.
